# How to create a query that parse's a field

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a simple SQL query that looks like the following

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM
    database.dbo.AView AS a
WHERE 
    a.Name = 'Messages' 
ORDER BY 
    a.Time DESC
```

1. `Field3` contains a paragraph of information and I am only interested in a small block of text.
2. The block begins with the word "detail" and ends with "property1"

How can I display all three columns, with `Field3` being just the block of text I am interested in?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: You mean [SUBSTRING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp)?

Comment: Best answer would likely be the use of regex, and there is no standard for that, so answer will need to be DBMS-specific.

Comment: The DBMS is SQL Server 2014